# SocketIO Client in Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, socket.io

SocketIO client, running in the Docker container does not connect to the server (not the Docker).

Without Docker, the client works well. But from the Docker, the client cannot connect to the server.
If you run client containers in Host-network mode on the same machine as the server and connect to the address 0.0.0.0, the connection will work. But this only works when everything is on the same instance, and I need another solution.
I tried some manipulations with exposing ports, but it did not help.

Server code:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("Wow! Client socket connected!");
});
server.listen(8081, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log("Starting server on port 8081");
});
```

Client code that should run in Docker:

```
let serverAddress = "address-of-the-server:8081";
const socketIOClient = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = socketIOClient(serverAddress);
```

What am I doing wrong, why the client can not connect to the server? Does the container need any special ports?

Comment: Can you include your `docker run` command(s) or `docker-compose.yml` file?  Are you trying to run both halves in containers?  On the same system or separate systems?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I use standard `docker run image-name`. I tried to expose the ports, but it did not help. On the same system there are no problems, whether I run in the container or not, I can connect via `--network=host`. But when it should be in separate systems, I get lost... I think maybe  I need something with a custom Docker network here?

Comment: Can you solve this? I have the same problem, thanks for all  best regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `address-of-the-server` I guess. To be sure, start your container like this:

```
docker run ... --network=host <image_name>
```

And use `localhost` instead of `address-of-the-server`.

Comment: I know, and it works. But I need to run the containers outside the instance with the server. Therefore, I am looking for another option.

Answer (score 0):

You must have figured out something by now, but for anybody else who lands here... I was facing the same problem, although I had feathers on both sides (feathers-vuex). Like your setup, the client and server sides are in separate dockers, and they talk together fine as long as I'm running the browser on the same system that is running the docker, with the browser pointed at localhost. But I could not browse in from a different system. I banged my head on the wall for the longest time, trying to figure out how to get an environment variable or something from the host to the client IN THE BROWSER at run time, and nothing that I found on the Web was getting there. Finally I realized, with a big face palm, that the user typed the host system IP address into the address bar of the browser! I can just extract it from location.href! In my case we're going by IP addresses, but I guess something similar would work if you are using URLs. Hope this helps somebody.